# Problems with a getter for a 4x4 matrix in c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, return, tetris

Hello I have to program a tetris game in C by tomorrow and I'm having a bit of trouble with a getter that should return a sprite as a 4x4 matrix.

It most likely is pretty simple tho I am not that familiar with pointers to arrays.

so in the first file where I stored my shapes this is the test getter for 1 shape

```
int shape_i[4][4] = {
    {1,0,0,0},
    {1,0,0,0},
    {1,0,0,0},
    {1,0,0,0}
};


int **get_shape(){
return shape_i;}
```

now from my draw file I call it like this

```
void draw_shape(){
int **shape= get_shape();
for (int i = 0; i<4; i++){
    for (int j=0; j<4; j++){
        int value = shape[j][i];

            if (value != 0){
                SDL_Rect rect;
                rect.x = (get_x()+i)*BLOCK_WIDTH;
                rect.y = (get_y()+j) *BLOCK_HEIGHT;
                rect.h = BLOCK_HEIGHT;
                rect.w = BLOCK_WIDTH;
                SDL_FillRect(window,&rect,0x044DDE);
            }
            }
    }
SDL_Flip(window);
}
```

It doesn't give an error on compiling but my program stops once it reaches get_shape()

Comment: What error you have? It is not clear which is the desired output and which is the output you get instead.

Comment: It doesn't give me an error tho my window closes and stops running once it reaches get_shape()
if I replace **shape=get_shape();
with

int shape[4][4] =   { {1,0,0,0},
    {1,0,0,0},
    {1,0,0,0},
    {1,0,0,0}
};

it works just fine

Comment: And also the for loop are wrong, they should go from 0 to 3

Comment: @Teepeemm if is in the assignment then shape[4][4] = {...} is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR**: Copy the data to your shape array with `memcpy`, see second example below. The other examples are alternative approaches with explanations.

---

In C, you can't return arrays. You can only return a pointer to the first element to an array. The first element of your array is itself an array, an array of 4 `int`s.

The syntax to define a pointer to an array of four ints is somewhat baroque:

```
int (*p)[4];
```

It's even more baroque when you must define it as the return type of a function:

```
int (*get_shape(int c))[4] { ... }
```

A way around this is to use a `typedef`:

```
typedef int (*Shape)[4];
```

Now your variables and function prototype look like this:

```
Shape p = get_shape(c);

Shape get_shape(int c) { ... }
```

Here's a complete example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int (*Shape)[4];

int shape_i[4][4] = {{1,0,0,0}, {1,0,0,0}, {1,0,0,0}, {1,0,0,0}};
int shape_l[4][4] = {{1,0,0,0}, {1,0,0,0}, {1,1,0,0}, {0,0,0,0}};
int shape_z[4][4] = {{1,0,0,0}, {1,1,0,0}, {0,1,0,0}, {0,0,0,0}};

Shape get_shape(int c)
{
    switch (c) {
    case 'I':   return shape_i;
    case 'L':   return shape_l;
    case 'Z':   return shape_z;
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    int c;

    for (c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++) {
        Shape p = get_shape(c);

        if (p) {
            int i, j;

            for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                    putchar(p[j][i] ? '#' : ' ');
                }
                puts("");
            }
            puts("--");
        }        
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note how the definition of the shapes still require you to use `int[4][4]`, because arrays are not pointers. You need arrays where you define your data. Also note that this solution returns a pointer to the original `shape_i`. When you modify the data in `p`, you modify `shape_i` through `p`, thus destroying your shape prototype.

---

If you want to fill an array with data, just pass the data in. That's a common approach even for one-dimensional arrays: Pass an array and have the function fill it. Return an (otherwise unrelated) value that tells you whether the operation was successful.

```
int get_shape(int shape[4][4], int c)
{
    switch (c) {
    case 'I':   memcpy(shape, shape_i, sizeof(shape)); return 1;
    case 'L':   memcpy(shape, shape_l, sizeof(shape)); return 1;
    case 'Z':   memcpy(shape, shape_z, sizeof(shape)); return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`memcpy` is a function of the standard library for which you should include `<string.h>`. The return value is just to check whether the shape was valid. Use it like this:

```
int p[4][4];

if (get_shape('I')) {
    // p is now filled with a copy of shape_i
}
```

I think this is the method you should be using. It will copy the contents of `shape_t`to `p`, and that's what you want here. You are going to rotate and flip your current block `p`, whereas you want to keep your block prototype `shape_i` unchanged for future "clones".

---

I've said above that you can't return arrays in C. What you can do is to wrap your array in a `struct` and return that. Structs are passed per value and don't decay into pointers like arrays.

```
struct Shape {
    int data[4][4];
};

struct shape shape_i = {{{1,0,0,0}, {1,0,0,0}, {1,0,0,0}, {1,0,0,0}}};

struct Shape get_shape(void) {
    return shape_i;
};

struct Shape p = get_shape();
```

This will also copy the cntents, but you must access the elements as `p.data[i][j]`.

Comment: Wow thank you so much :D now I can continue now for a long programming night